# open/execute huge sql file

Tags: postgresql

I have SQL file using `PostgreSQL` with size about 7GB. How can I open/execute the SQL file? I have researched and tried using Navicat Premium, Razor SQL, HeidiSQL, Workbench. In all I get out of memory. I know for sure it is a PostgreSQL database dump.

Comment: use `psql -f large_file.sql`

Comment: or use " `\i` " to execute:  `psql -h host -p port -U user -d database -c "\i large_file.sql`"

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL database dumps are normally produced by the command line tool `pg_dump`, and expected to be used via either `pg_restore` or simply `psql` command line tools.

However, you can both backup and restore from [PgAdminIII](http://www.pgadmin.org/). The backup option is available via right-clicking either the server or any database or schema. The Restore option is available via right-clicking a database or schema.

[Here's a step-by-step example](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/tutorials-quickstarts/all-platforms/how-dump-and-restore-postgres-plus-databases) of how dump or restore a database using PgAdmin.

Answer (score 3):

[As a_horse_with_no_name answered in a comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134887/open-execute-huge-sql-file/134928#comment253343_134887):

> use `psql -f large_file.sql`